# Passing values from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, variables

I'm trying to get the value which is the id in the mysql database. However, each time I click on the image, I get `null`. I used `this` to get the value but it is not working as it keeps giving me `null` in the alert box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        mysql_select_db("ajax");
        $query="SELECT * FROM xxxx";
        $result= mysql_query($query);

        while($row=  mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<img src='".$row['filepath']."' value='".$row['ID']."' id='".$row['ID']."'   onclick='getrating(this.value);'>";

            echo "<br>";
       }
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        function getrating(row_id){
            var x = document.getElementById(row_id);
            alert(x);
        }
    </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Is this what was expected? If so, what is row_id in the JavaScript function? What is x? Is this as expected? Debugging starts with you. (Also, if you just need to pass values, no reason to use DOM element nodes.)

Comment: what 'value' do you think an image could have? I'll think you'll find that an `<img>` [doesn't have a value property](http://www.java2s.com/Code/HTMLCSSReference/HTML-Tag-Reference/imgJavaScriptProperties.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `getrating(this.id)` instead. Images don't have a `value` property.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I CANNOT THANK YOU ENOUGH.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 echo "<img src='".$row['filepath']."' id='".$row['ID']."' onclick='getrating(".$row['ID'].");'>";
```

Comment: Wouldn't this allow duplicate element ids if the row id value is the same as another id somewhere in the form?

Comment: i did that and got [object HTMLImageElement], so then i added value here," var x = document.getElementById(row_id).value;" but now i get undefined. can u help? thanks

Comment: @mayank23 Your element is an IMG, and as I said, IMG tags don't have 'value' attributes. You could use the id itself, or maybe a data- field. Since the "value" you're after is the same thing you're using as the ID anyway, it seems a redundant step though.

Comment: If you get [object HTMLImageElement] you can get directly the image ID by using function getRating(img) { var id = img.id; }

Answer (score 1):

Or you can pass this.id

```
<img id="row_12" onclick="getrating(this.id)" alt="image"/>



function getrating(id){
    alert(id);
}
```

Or you can use the event object and the currentTarget propety

```
<img id="row_12" onclick="getrating(event)" alt="image"/>



function getrating(e){
    alert(e.currentTarget.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` isn't a valid attribute of the `img` tag. You could use the `id`, or just do

```
echo "<img ... onclick='getrating($row[ID]);'>";
```

Comment: Wouldn't this allow duplicate element ids if the row id value is the same as another id somewhere in the form?

Comment: No more so than `id='".$row['ID']."'`, but that's another issue.

Comment: Another issue but still true, though.. mayank23 should try to avoid using the `id` as a value for the `id` unless it was unlikely to repeat in other parts of the code

Comment: thank you very much for this, since this "$row[ID]" was what i needed for the parameter for getrating().

Answer (score 0):

An `<img>` doesn't have a value property.

You are doing unnecessary work in your function too. Your code should look like this:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        mysql_select_db("ajax");
        $query="SELECT * FROM xxxx";
        $result= mysql_query($query);

        while($row=  mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<img src='".$row['filepath']."' value='".$row['ID']."' id='".$row['ID']."'   onclick='getrating(this);'>";

            echo "<br>";
       }
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        function getrating(element){
            alert(element);
        }
    </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

By passing `this` to your function through the onclick event, you already have the element you are looking for without needing to use `document.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 0):

They way how you escape the ID could be the problem. I know this is already answered but just in case for those people who needs another solution.

```
onclick="getrating(\''.$row['ID'].'\')"
```