# Need to pass a value from PHP to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I need to pass a value from PHP back to my javascript. I have tried so many things but can't get it to work. Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    life = {};
    life.anjaxEnter = function(finished) {
        $.ajax({
        dataType:"json",
        type:"POST",
        data:mydata,
        url:"myurl.php",
        async:false,
        success:life.receiveResult,
        });
        setTimeout("location.href='myredirectionurl'", 1000); // Redirect after 1 second
    }
    life.receiveResult = function(result) {
        alert(result);
    }   
</script>
```

I need to pass a specific value from the PHP file back to life.receiveResult and then add this to the redirection url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass these strings from php to javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174092/how-to-pass-these-strings-from-php-to-javascript) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626183/passing-values-from-php-to-javascript?rq=1

Comment: you have an extra comma after susccess

Comment: Can you search before posting questions. I’ve seen this question answered dozens of times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had seen answers as well, however, they did not seem to work for me. Got it working now though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem is probably that at the time when you assign `life.receiveResult` to `success`, **`life.receiveResult` is `undefined`**. You need to define it before you assign it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

`myurl.php` needs to return a JSON result when it's called. Something like this:

```php
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/json");
$mydata = "Hello";
echo json_encode(array('ok' => true, 'mydata' => $mydata));
?>
```

Have a look at the [json_encode](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) docs, the [header docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) and some of the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174092/how-to-pass-these-strings-from-php-to-javascript?rq=1) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682260/returning-json-from-php-to-javascript) for more information.